# Android - ClassCastException in publishResults method in Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I'm currently creating an activity where you can select users from a list and filter them by typing a part of their name. I'm making use of a custom ArrayAdapter with input coming from a UserSelect-class (int id, String name, boolean selected).

My current problem is that I get a ClassCastException in method publishResults and more specific in this line:

```
users = (ArrayList<UserSelect>)filterResults.values;
```

Any idea how to fix this? Previously I worked with a string[] and that worked, but since I need the id from the object I'm currently changes this to ArrayList.

Full code:

```
public class CCSelectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

  private final Context context;
  private List<UserSelect> users = new ArrayList<UserSelect>();

  public CCSelectAdapter(Context context,  List<UserSelect> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_cc_select);
    this.context = context;
    this.users = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cc_select, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ccName);
    textView.setText(users.get(position).getName());

    return rowView;
  }

  public int getCount() 
  {
    return users.size();
  }

  public String getItem(int position) 
  {
      return users.get(position).getName();
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) 
  {
      return position;
  }

  @Override
  public Filter getFilter()
  {
     return new Filter()
     {
          @Override
          protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)
          {
              FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

              if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
              {
                  results.values = users;
                  results.count = users.size();
              }
              else
              {
                  List<String> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<String>();

                  for (int i = 1 ; i < users.size() ; i++) {
                      if(users.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(((String) charSequence).toLowerCase()))
                      {
                          filterResultsData.add(users.get(i).getName());
                      }
                  }

                  String[] arr = filterResultsData.toArray(new String[filterResultsData.size()]);

                  results.values = arr;
                  results.count = arr.length;
              }
              return results;
          }

          @Override
          protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
          {
            users = (ArrayList<UserSelect>)filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      };
  }

}
```

**Solution** (thanks to Elltz):
I changed:

```
List<String> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to:

```
List<UserSelect> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<UserSelect>();
```

Comment: Debug the name of the class :) `Log.d("Daemun", "filterResults.values class = " + filterResults.values.getClass().getName());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check my answer here from another different tag [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331445/incompatible-return-type-within-customlist/26331558#26331558)

your problem is your arraylist is a string generic type and you are casting it to

```
 filterResults.values
```

which im thinking is a

```
 UserSelect object
```

so change your arraylist to

```
<UserSelect>
```

Comment: Great, it works! Now I can start banging my head against the wall for other bugs in my code :-D

Answer (score 0):

Is the `FilterResults` object that you are passing to `publishResults` the one that you are building in `performFiltering`? If so, notice that the values field is of type `String[]`, not `ArrayList<UserSelect>`.

A cast operator only works if the underlying object actually has that type.